# Gulp-Coveralls returns 422, no TravisCI builds can be found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, travis-ci, coveralls

TravisCI builds are passing for my open-source project, and I'm now trying to integrate gulp-coveralls. On Coveralls.io, no builds can be found for my repository, even though Travis builds have run successfully since I added my repo to Coveralls.

```
'There have been no builds for this repo.'
```

When I try to run my gulp-coveralls gulp task, I get this error:

```
'Repo token could not be determined.  Continuing without it.'
Error in plugin 'gulp-coveralls'
Bad response:422 {"message":"Couldn't find a repository matching this job.","error":true}
    at handleError (/Users/sarah.green/angular-embedly/node_modules/gulp-coveralls/index.js:11:30)
    at sendToCoverallsCallback (/Users/sarah.green/angular-embedly/node_modules/gulp-coveralls/index.js:19:9)
    at /Users/sarah.green/angular-embedly/node_modules/gulp-coveralls/index.js:31:13
    at Request._callback (/Users/sarah.green/angular-embedly/node_modules/gulp-coveralls/node_modules/coveralls/lib/sendToCoveralls.js:7:5)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/sarah.green/angular-embedly/node_modules/gulp-coveralls/node_modules/coveralls/node_modules/request/index.js:142:22)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/sarah.green/angular-embedly/node_modules/gulp-coveralls/node_modules/coveralls/node_modules/request/index.js:856:14)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/sarah.green/angular-embedly/node_modules/gulp-coveralls/node_modules/coveralls/node_modules/request/index.js:808:12)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at _stream_readable.js:919:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
```

Here's what I've got so far:

gulp-coveralls in my dev dependencies in package.json

gulpfile.js:

```
var coveralls = require('gulp-coveralls');
...
gulp.task('coveralls', function () {
gulp.src('coverage/**/lcov.info')
  .pipe(coveralls());
});
```

karma.conf.js:

```
coverageReporter: {
    type : 'lcov',
    dir : 'coverage/'
}
```

Github: https://github.com/lithiumtech/angular-embedly

I use Karma and PhantomJS to run my tests. The file coverage/lcov.info is definitely being generated. Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so, can you mark it as the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

Sarah,

What you are missing is a coveralls repository token. You must go to coveralls.io and create a login using your GitHub account. This will then pull all your repos into coveralls. Then for the repo that you want to use coveralls with, you turn coveralls on by clicking the "Off" switch.

Now click the "view on coveralls" button and it will show you your repo key. You can then set it up by creating a .coveralls.yml file and copying your keys into that file. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a mistake in your .coveralls.yml file. If you are using Travis CI, try this:

```
service_name: travis-ci
repo_token: token_given
```

and if you're using Travis Pro:

```
service_name: travis-pro
repo_token: token_given
```

I hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

For GitHub builds running in [travis-ci.org](https://travis-ci.org/) you don't need a service name in your .coveralls.yml file, just the token. You don't need a passing build in Travis either, just successfully generated LCOV data and a plugin that sends it.

I had one issue with gulp-coveralls where the LCOV data was not sent properly to coveralls, when read from file using `gulp.src`. The only way I it would work finally was if the LCOV data was sent to the plugin directly, rather than using an intermediary file to store it to first.

To have both LCOV data piped to gulp-coveralls *and* have a JSON/HTML report, finally I resorted to `lazy-pipe` to create reusable steps.

The complete project can be found at GitHub's [angular-logger](https://github.com/pdorgambide/angular-logger)

```
// .coveralls.yml
repo_token: the_token
```

```js
var jasmine = require('gulp-jasmine');
var cover = require('gulp-coverage');
var coveralls = require('gulp-coveralls');
var lazypipe = require('lazypipe');

(..)

// gulpfile.js
var testAndGather = lazypipe()
    .pipe(cover.instrument, {
        pattern: ['src/**/*.js'],
        debugDirectory: 'debug'
    })
    .pipe(jasmine, {includeStackTrace: true})
    .pipe(cover.gather);

gulp.task('test', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.src('spec/**/*spec.js')
        .pipe(testAndGather())
        .pipe(cover.format(['html']))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('reports'));
});

gulp.task('travis', ['build'], function () {
    gulp.src('spec/**/*spec.js')
        .pipe(testAndGather())
        .pipe(cover.format(['lcov']))
        .pipe(coveralls()); // directly pipe into coveralls
});
```

Using:

```
"gulp-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
"gulp-coverage": "~0.3.35",
"gulp-coveralls": "~0.1.4",
"lazypipe": "~0.2.3"
```